# Can we run queries in handlebar helpers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

I am in need to check a book whether subscribed the user or not. So i am running queries in a handlebar helper function.

```
//hbs helper function
checkIfSubed: function(bookId, userId, options){
    console.log(bookId);
    console.log(userId);
    Subscription.findOne({
        book: bookId,
        user: userId
    })
    .select('user book')
    .then(function(doc){
        if(doc)
        return (doc != null) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Below code in html template

```
{{#checkIfSubed _id ../user._id}}
    <p>hi</p>
{{else}}
    <p>bye</p>
{{/checkIfSubed}}
```

But i am not getting the return result, please help..

Comment: well that is making an asynchronous call and there is no way you can return from it and last time I worked with handlebars it did not have asynchronous support so I think you need to rethink the bindings. Probably be better off processing it all than binding it to the template.

Comment: Ok, let me know, if there any other alternatives.. I need to check whether the book is subscribed or not, by a logged in user